# Efficient JSP/Tomcat persistent store?

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tomcat, in-memory-database

I have some pretty much barebones JSP apps running on top of Apache Tomcat 6.

The server handles about ~100.000 requests per app per day. 
Since the apps depend on a number of network elements, there is a lot of configuration parameters to be setup. However, once setup I want all the sessions to share the same data.

Reading from disk the whole time does not seem like a proper solution. Nor would reading from a database work for me (various limitations).

Is there a proven, reliable  in-memory persistent store compatible with JSP/Java that all of the loaded JSP sessions could use for loading config data ?

[EDIT] I don't want to do too much heavy-lifting or refactoring for this. It should be a stupid, simple datastore with clean interface (possibly of command-response type), so no heavy-duty frameworks and libs.

Comment: @SayemAhmed - No, please see my edit.

Comment: MongoDB ... http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Caching

Answer (score 1):

You can try [HSQL DB](http://hsqldb.org/), it provides in-memory storing which is what you want. It's written in Java, so it's 100% compatible with your project.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a long shot, but you could use Apache Derby, this will give you a really fast access to data (as it's in memory) while at the same time being extremely lightweight.

http://db.apache.org/derby/

Comment: Is it also storing the data in-memory or is only the process in-memory ?